# Google App Engine about key in ndb

Tags: google-app-engine, key, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am new in web development and also in google app engine. I dont really understand what the function of key in ndb, i think it is like a primary key for each row? If the function of key is to identified any rows in each entities, can I use it to do the query?

I also do not understand how to retrieve the key in each rows. In the docs we should use this code to return key, and also store to database.

```
sandy_key = sandy.put()
```

What if i do not want to store anything but i only want to retrieve the key. For example:

```
class Post(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    content = ndb.TextProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

And then I do a query.

```
q = Post.query(Post.title == "test")
```

Is it possible to get the key from that query?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually looking for the entity's id (or identifier).  An entity's *key* is made up of an identifier and a kind.  The kind is typically the name of the Model, which in your case is "Post".

You can retrieve an entity's id using the .id() method.  In your example, you must first "fetch" or "get" an entity.  You provided a query.  If you were to fetch one entity matching your query and find the id of that entity, your code would look like this:

```
q = Post.query(Post.title == "test")
my_entity = q.fetch(1, keys_only=True)
my_key = my_entity.id()
```

The "keys_only" parameter in the fetch is not necessary, but it does save resources because it tells the fetch to only retrieve the key.

This information is explained in the [NDB Entity Keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities?hl=id#entity_keys) documentation.

Comment: It's working. Its all about fetch and get command, after using get/fetch I can see the real structure of each entities. Thank you so much sir